# Add-In Error: Content is blocked because it isn't signed by a valid security certificate

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm working on an Outlook Add-In application and finding myself unable to run it locally with the following message appearing when trying to run it in the "Office Desktop Client":

"Add-in Error the content is blocked because it isn't signed by a valid security certificate"

When I try to run the Add-In using Chrome or Edge, I instead get the following message in the Add-In:

"Add-in Error: Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator."

If I try hitting "Retry" on Chrome or Edge I get the following Add-In error:

"This add-in may not load properly, but you can still try to start it."

And when I hit start on that I get the following:

"The webpage at https://localhost:44364/AddinClient?et=#/read might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

When trying to go to this address manually via chrome in a new tab it manages to load in that tab that is after a "This site is note secure" warning

I've noticed some common fixes for this problem such as adding localhost to trusted sites in internet options and installing office-addin-dev-certs, however neither of these options have fixed the problem (I have also tried deleting and re-installing the certificate which I've seen come up various times).

Is there anything else I could be trying?

For some technical details about my setup, I'm using Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20270) 64-bit.  I'm using Windows 10 Pro and the manifest file for the Add-in is the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:b1287d2e-c737-4a6d-84ad-8c25896b50dc-->
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>01fa9df4-6148-4299-b9f6-92898abce052</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Test</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-GB</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Outlook Addin Dev" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Outlook Addin Dev"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/icon64.png"/>

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.MyTestSite.com" />
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:44364</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.5" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

            <!-- Message Read -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                <Group id="loadAddinGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="loadAddinOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneButtonLabel" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneSuperTipTitle" />
                      <Description resid="paneSuperTipDescription" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon64" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Items>
                      <Item id="mainCmd">
                        <Label resid="paneButtonLabel"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="paneButtonLabel"/>
                          <Description resid="paneSuperTipDescription"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Icon>
                          <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                          <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                          <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon64" />
                          <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                        </Icon>
                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                          <SourceLocation resid="loadAddinTaskPaneUrl" />
                          <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                        </Action>
                      </Item>
                      <Item id="signOutCmd">
                        <Label resid="paneSignOutLabel"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="paneSignOutLabel"/>
                          <Description resid="paneSignOutSuperTipDescription"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Icon>
                          <bt:Image size="16" resid="cog16" />
                          <bt:Image size="32" resid="cog32" />
                          <bt:Image size="64" resid="cog64" />
                          <bt:Image size="80" resid="cog80" />
                        </Icon>
                        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                          <FunctionName>signOut</FunctionName>
                        </Action>
                      </Item>
                    </Items>
                  </Control>
                  <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="composeAddInGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeFunctionButton">
                    <Label resid="paneAddCC"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneAddCC"/>
                      <Description resid="paneSuperTipDescription"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon64" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="loadAddInComposePaneUrl" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>

      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/icon16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/icon32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon64" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/icon64.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/icon80.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="cog16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/cog16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="cog32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/cog32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="cog64" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/cog64.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="cog80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient/assets/images/cog80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="loadAddinTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient#/read"/>
          <bt:Url id="loadAddInComposePaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AddinClient#/compose"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-In"/>
          <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="Add-In"/>
          <bt:String id="paneButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Add-In"/>
          <bt:String id="paneSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Add-In"/>
          <bt:String id="paneSignOutLabel" DefaultValue="Sign Out"/>
          <bt:String id="paneAddCC" DefaultValue="Add-In"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="paneSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens the outlook addin."/>
          <bt:String id="paneSignOutSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Sign Out of outlook addin"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"This site is note secure"** explains that issue is due to the certificate. To fix this issue you need to install this certificate on your local machine inside certificate store to accept that as valid certificate.

Also one think you can try is using http and check if that works for you.
accept the warning and allow the site to load unsecure site and once it loads you can view certificate and store inside certificate store of your machine.

I am unsure of how add-ins works but will give it try and update you if you want.

Comment: Thanks it was the certificate, googled some steps and got it added.